# Compare data annotation is inconsistent for confirming password

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-annotations, blazor

I have a simple register form which has password confirmation where you just repeat the password, you know the drill.

Now to check if passwords are the same I use data annotation named Compare

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Must be at least 4 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password confirmation is required")]
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Must be at least 4 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "Passwords should be the same.")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
```

And form looks basically like this:

```
<EditForm class="form-signin" OnValidSubmit="OnSubmit" Model="registerParameters">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<h4 class="font-weight-normal text-center">Create Account</h4>

<label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">User Name</label>
<InputText id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus @bind-Value="@registerParameters.UserName" />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => registerParameters.UserName)" />

<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<InputText type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" @bind-Value="@registerParameters.Password" />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => registerParameters.Password)" />

<label for="inputPasswordConfirm" class="sr-only">Password Confirmation</label>
<InputText type="password" id="inputPasswordConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Password Confirmation" @bind-Value="@registerParameters.PasswordConfirm" />
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => registerParameters.PasswordConfirm)" />

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Create account</button>

<label class="text-danger">@error</label>
<NavLink href="login">
    <h6 class="font-weight-normal text-center">Already have an account? Click here to login</h6>
</NavLink>
</EditForm>

@functions{

RegisterParametersDto registerParameters { get; set; } = new RegisterParametersDto();
dynamic dyn;
string error { get; set; }

async Task OnSubmit()
{
    error = null;
    try
    {
        await authStateProvider.Register(registerParameters);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ex.Message);
        error = dyn.errorMessage;
    }
}
}
```

Now, whenever those passwords don't match, it will show the error message properly, but when I try to submit, it disappears completely. How can I fix this?

EDIT:
I'll add that the compare annotation is the only one that acts this way. If the password confirm is too short, proper error will show and won't disappear after pressing submit button.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the actual question here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I pressed enter and accidentally submitted the question when it wasn't finished yet. I couldn't find a delete option so I was hoping I will edit this in time before anyone will see. Now it is complete. EDIT: Now it appeared for some reason. I swear the delete button wasn't there!

Comment: When you say "it disappears completely", what disappears?

Comment: The error message saying that those passwords don't match disappears and doesn't come back unless I add at least a single character to any of those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since then I've changed data annotation for fluent validation and it works beautifully and the error has disappeared, so I guess that's another reason to use fluent validation instead.